# Microsoft iSCSI Initiator: How to pass a CHAP user name?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, iscsi

I need to connect a Win2008 R2 server to a iSCSI target and I'm supposed to use a CHAP user name that is different from the initiator name.

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759052.aspx) says:

> By default, the Microsoft iSCSI Initiator service uses the initiator node name as the CHAP username. You can override this action by passing a CHAP username to the login request.

Now my question is: How and where can I override this? At least using the GUI, I couldn't find a way to specify a CHAP user name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When connecting to the target you have to select the "Advanced" button and then specify the name under the "Enable CHAP" log on" options.

Comment: Thank you very much, pretty obvious now, argh! However it still didn't work this way, for whatever reason. It finally worked using the command-line tool: `iscsicli QAddTargetPortal IP user password`, the rest I could do successfully via the GUI.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.